# Applications included as part of operating system or not - what's the difference?

Tags: performance, operating-system

A question I've been given to study with is this:

Q: Should an operating system include common applications such as web browsers and mail programs or not?

The answer I was given to this question is: Pros: better performance and integration if it is included as part of the OS. Cons: The OS is burdened with additional functionality.

I am clearly lacking understanding of something here, because I don't see what the difference would be. In the end, I don't see what the difference is between making a browser "part of the operating system", or making is separate. I suppose I don't really understand what it means to be "part of the operating system". I don't understand why an OS would be burdened more in one situation that the other.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: Look at Microsoft and how it got sued for including IE in the OS distro.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If an application is included in an OS it

- is convenient for the average user who doesn't have to choose and install software
- is sometimes inconvenient to remove (like system apps in some mobile OS which you can't unistall easily)
- can be tightly coupled with other application that are included (like browser + pdf viewer or media player) that wouldn't necessarily be available on other systems, increasing its functionality
- probably doesn't need to support other OS and development is concentrated on integration with the OS it is bundled with
- takes up disc/disk space - which was more a problem when OS used to be delivered on floppy disks or CDs and hard disk space was expensive

The main reason to include software probably is to tie the customers to the product. The application maybe is developed by the OS manufacturer or they got paid to include it. There have been lawsuits because of this, which resulted for example in the *Windows N* editions (without the windows media player) or the web browser choice screen in european versions of the Internet Explorer.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure this is the correct stackexchange for this question, perhaps http://programmers.stackexchange.com

First off, what makes up an "Operating System" is a little bit nebulous, one might argue that the Browser is not "part of" the OS, but merely bundled with it.

For the purposes of this question, I think part of the operating system means it comes out of the box with that app installed (regardless of whether the app is "part of the operating system" in a deeper sense).

The automatic update mechanism, for example, might treat the app as seperate and update it separate from the OS, or even allow it to be uninstalled from the system, but that doesn't change the fact that the machine came with that app.